# Nopcommerce nivo slider view not found in production environment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

With my visual studio 2012, there is no problem with the binary version of nopcommerce 3.0. But in the production environment, it shows the following error for the home page:

> The view
>   'Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo' or
>   its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched
>   locations. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Themes/DefaultClean/Views/WidgetsNivoSlider/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.cshtml
>   ~/Themes/DefaultClean/Views/WidgetsNivoSlider/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.vbhtml
>   ~/Themes/DefaultClean/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.cshtml
>   ~/Themes/DefaultClean/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/WidgetsNivoSlider/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.cshtml
>   ~/Views/WidgetsNivoSlider/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.vbhtml
>   ~/Administration/Views/WidgetsNivoSlider/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.cshtml
>   ~/Administration/Views/WidgetsNivoSlider/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.vbhtml
>   ~/Administration/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.cshtml
>   ~/Administration/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.vbhtml
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The view
>   'Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo' or
>   its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched
>   locations. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Themes/DefaultClean/Views/WidgetsNivoSlider/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.cshtml
>   ~/Themes/DefaultClean/Views/WidgetsNivoSlider/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.vbhtml
>   ~/Themes/DefaultClean/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.cshtml
>   ~/Themes/DefaultClean/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/WidgetsNivoSlider/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.cshtml
>   ~/Views/WidgetsNivoSlider/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.vbhtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.vbhtml
>   ~/Administration/Views/WidgetsNivoSlider/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.cshtml
>   ~/Administration/Views/WidgetsNivoSlider/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.vbhtml
>   ~/Administration/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.cshtml
>   ~/Administration/Views/Shared/Nop.Plugin.Widgets.NivoSlider.Views.WidgetsNivoSlider.PublicInfo.vbhtml
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 3:  @foreach (var widget in Model) Line 4:  { Line 5:
>   @Html.Action(widget.ActionName, widget.ControllerName,
>   widget.RouteValues) Line 6:  }

Any suggestions please?

Comment: I ended up downloading latest binary version and working on it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Even the post is quite old but I think answer can help others. Here is the solution for the problem.

The error comes when we publish the project with precompile option selected. If you publish the project without precompiling, you will not face this issue. Because there are some embedded views which do not work properly when we enable precompiling at the time of publishing.

Comment: if admin panel does not work, follow these steps.
Publish the Nop.Web and Nop.Admin web applications to the same directory, as follows
1. Publish Nop.Web to the Published\Web\ directory.
2. Publish Nop.Admin to the Published\Web\Administration\ directory.
3. Select all the files in Published\Web\ directory and upload them to your web server.
4. Make sure the .dlls from Nop.Admin (Published\Web\Administration\bin\) are moved and exist in Published\Web\bin

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an publishing error. It seems you have the views in place and they work correctly on your machine, but on the server it's missing some files that didn't get pushed on your FTP, Web Publish, or other form of deploy you're using.

Try to answer these questions and I'm positive you'll find the culprit:

- If you're able to remote desktop to your server can you verify the files exist?
- What kind of publishing profile are your using? have you tried publishing locally and verify that the file exist there?
- If nopCommerce was added using a nuget package, did you make sure to include the files under source control?
- Is this a problem only on your workstation? or do any of your co-workers experience the same thing?